# Java Date field not shown properly in postman

Tags: spring-boot, jackson-databind

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
I am using Spring Boot 2.56
The date and time show properly for field "transactionDate" field when debugging the code in intellij.
2023-01-15 23:35:05.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z3h5.jpg)

Code:

```
public List < TransactionEntity > findByFromAccountIdOrToAccountId(Long accountId) {
   AccountEntity account = accountRepository.findByAccountId(accountId);
   if (account == null) {
       throw new AccountException("account cannot be found in account table accountId:" + accountId);
   }

   List < TransactionEntity > list = transactionRepository.findByFromAccountOrToAccount(account, account);
   return list;
}

TransactionEntity.java
private Timestamp transactionDate;
```

For the `transactionDate` field I used import java.sql.Timestamp;
In postman it is showing: `"transactionDate": 1673843714000,`

How can I show the proper date and time in postman result such as "2023-01-15 23:35:05.0".

Comment: Do not use `java.sql.Timestamp` if there is any way to avoid it. For a timestamp use `OffsetDateTIme` or `Instant` or as a last resort `LocalDateTime` if you are sure to keep track of which time zone it belongs to, because `LocalDateTime` does not do that for you. The mentioned types are all from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. `Timestamp` was a genuine hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class that no one should want to use anymore either.

Answer (score 0):

> "transactionDate": 1673843714000

This is how Timestamp looks like. If you want to show like you mention use **LocalDateTime** instead.

```
private LocalDateTime transactionDate;
```

Or convert

```
transactionDate.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate()
```